# Trying to use an array list to create doubles of each index. Copying doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

The example input would be {1, 2, 3}. Example output would be {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}. What I get is {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}. My code is

```
public void doubleList(ArrayList<String> string){
    int length = string.size();
    string.add(1, string.get(0));
    for(int x = 2; x < length; x++){
    string.add(x+2, string.get(x));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but I'd like some help as it seems to make sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you debug to see what was going on?

Answer (score 0):

the length of array is still 3 so it'll stop when reach first loop 
it'll be like this

length:3

arraylist:{1,1,2,3}

firstloop:{1,1,2,3,2}
x=3 (because you assign x=2)
i think you should store the array you want copy to another array and assign it to array like this

```
public void doubleList(ArrayList<String> string){
    ArrayList<String> arrCpy=(ArrayList)string.clone();
    int length = string.size();

    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++){
        string.add(x*2, arrCpy.get(x));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw what you want to happen:

```
1  2  3

1  1  2  3
│  ↑
└──┘ copy index 0 to index 1

1  1  2  2  3
      │  ↑
      └──┘ copy index 2 to index 3

1  1  2  2  3  3
            │  ↑
            └──┘ copy index 4 to index 5
```

Now you just need to write the code doing this.

Comment: Could alternatively copy to the same index.

Comment: uhmm, can I ask how can I draw the arrow like yours?

Comment: @DangNguyen I did web search for [`unicode arrow`](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+arrow) and copy/pasted the ↑ directly from the search result list, and I searched for [`unicode box drawing`](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+box+drawing) and copy/pasted the line characters from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) page.

Comment: @Gendarme Copy to same index would just make the `add()` have to shift one more value, so *slight* impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through the list and add a duplicate of each element. However, after you add, you will have an additional element in the list, so you'll have to jump two steps forward each iteration.

```
int originalSize = list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < originalSize; i++) {
    list.add(2*i, list.get(2*i));
}
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/ZDHAVM98231) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, start by copying the index 0 adding it to de current index + 1, then increment the index by 2 and so on.

```
  public static void doubleList(ArrayList<String> string){
      for(int x = 0; x < string.size(); x+=2){
          string.add(x + 1, string.get(x));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void doubleList(ArrayList<String> string) {
        int length = string.size();
        int y = 0;      
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {          
            string.add(y, string.get(y));
            y+=2;
        }
    }
```